# How to perform search on SharePoint list bound to a gridview

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, asp.net, gridview

I have a SharePoint list which is bound to an asp.net gridview, I further want to search every column.

Is there a way to perform such a search wherein there is no database, but search should be performed based on the values in the datatable of the gridview.

I have seen posts where a Jquery plug-in DataTable is used. But I would prefer actual code.

Kindly help. Thank you! :)

Comment: Are you want to implement search on asp.net grid view OR html table ?

Comment: on asp.net grid view @Vishal

Answer (score 2):

Place a search box and button on button click query your datasource i believe its List in this case

```
public void Search(string searchText)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("mySite");


            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("myList");

            SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='searchColum' /><Value Type='valType'>" + searchText + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
            SP.ListItemCollection listItemColl = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItemColl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            //Convert listItemColl to dataTable and bind grid

}
```

Refer the answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223223/how-to-keep-the-values-of-the-dropdown-list-in-edit-mode)
You can reuse the code at link by creating the CAML query dynamically to query the List.